# Try to insert a record into a table with select and join

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently write a insert statement and it gave me "ORA-00923: From keyword not found where expected. Is there any way that I can accomplish this? Thanks. Here is the statement:

```
Insert into seda_owner.seda_lookup(table_name,description,sequence,value)
Select 'DEFAULT_CATE_CHG_ITEMS_DOCS','Software Requirements Specification', '1', 
  (select **value** from seda_owner.seda_document a 
   join seda_owner.seda_lookup b 
    on b.value = a.guid and description = 'Software Requirements Specification');
```

What I try to do is passing 3 strings table_name,description and sequence and one variable value to table seda_lookup.

Comment: problem seems to be in your variable value, try to pass values with static value in variable. This will give u more info where to fix the issue.

Comment: Try Select 'DEFAULT_CATE_CHG_ITEMS_DOCS','Software Requirements Specification', '1', E.value from
  (select **value** from seda_owner.seda_document a 
   join seda_owner.seda_lookup b 
    on b.value = a.guid and description = 'Software Requirements Specification') E; instead? using the subquery as a table in its own right

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, select statements always need `from tableName`. The outer select of you query does not have such a from clause.

```
Insert into seda_owner.seda_lookup(table_name,description,sequence,value)
Select 'DEFAULT_CATE_CHG_ITEMS_DOCS','Software Requirements Specification', '1', 
  (select **value** from seda_owner.seda_document a 
   inner join seda_owner.seda_lookup b 
    on b.value = a.guid and description = 'Software Requirements Specification')
from dual;
```

Even better:

```
Insert into seda_owner.seda_lookup(table_name,description,sequence,value)
Select 'DEFAULT_CATE_CHG_ITEMS_DOCS','Software Requirements Specification', 
    '1', **value** 
from seda_owner.seda_document a 
inner join seda_owner.seda_lookup b 
    on b.value = a.guid and description = 'Software Requirements Specification'
```

The first solution requires one and only one row to be returned by sub-query.

The second solution will insert as many records as defined by the inner join.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are the asterisks around **value** part of your code? Or were you just trying to **bold** that word?
2. Maybe your nested select is returning more than one row
3. Is **value** only in b? You don't qualify it in your **select**, but you do qualify it in the join criteria (b.value)

Comment: Can't know if the nested select returns more than one row. The error given happens at parse, nothing is executed yet. So possibility 2 may be a problem, but only after the syntax is fixed.

Comment: Run the nested select by itself to see the results (i.e., to see how many rows it returns.)